# Pandas better way to get rows that has all columns null except one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has 100 columns where the first column is a unique identifier and the second column is the group that they belong to and rest of the column explains each user's characteristics.

```
user_id, group_id, a, b, c,....,az
0001, 1, 23, pro, 5.5, ......, 234
0002, 1, 32, che, 3.3, ......, 342
0003, 2, NaN, NaN, NaN,......., NaN
```

I want to subset all the records that have `NaN`(s) all the columns except for column 1 and column 2 (`user_id`, `group_id`)

One way to do is: 
`df[df['a'].notnull() & (df['b'].notnull()) & (df['c'].notnull())]` but writing for 98 columns like this seems inneficient. Is there a betterway?

Comment: You want all rows where columns a through az are NaN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [197]: df[df.iloc[:, 2:].notna().all(1)]
Out[197]:
   user_id  group_id     a    b    c     az
0        1         1  23.0  pro  5.5  234.0
1        2         1  32.0  che  3.3  342.0
```

if `user_id` and `group_id` are **always**  set and can never be NaN's:

```
In [205]: df[df.notna().sum(1).gt(2)]
Out[205]:
   user_id  group_id     a    b    c     az
0        1         1  23.0  pro  5.5  234.0
1        2         1  32.0  che  3.3  342.0
```

PS older Pandas versions don't have `DataFrame.notna()` method - in this case use `DataFrame..notnull()` method

**UPDATE:**

to select rows where all columns except first two have all `NAN` values:

```
In [215]: df[df.iloc[:, 2:].isnull().all(1)]
Out[215]:
   user_id  group_id   a    b   c  az
2        3         2 NaN  NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: shouldn't it be notnull, I can't seem to find notna method

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, newer Pandas versions also have `notna()`, `isna()` methods, for older Pandas versions - use `notnull()` and `isnull()`

Comment: how can i get the null rows to subset tried isnull but but when i check the numbers it didn't add up

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, you mean those rows where all columns (except first two) are NaN's or any?

Comment: yes exactly, tried isnull but didn't really work. (Except First two)

Answer (score 4):

You might drop the `user_id` and `group_id` columns first, test the nulls, then subset:

```
df[df.drop(['user_id', 'group_id'], axis=1).notnull().all(axis=1)]

#   user_id  group_id     a    b    c     az
#0        1         1  23.0  pro  5.5  234.0
#1        2         1  32.0  che  3.3  342.0
```

Or if the two columns' positions are fixed at 0 and 1:

```
df[df.iloc[:,2:].notnull().all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I will using `dropna` + `thresh`, basically it adding the tolerance for Number of NaNs per row.

```
df.dropna(axis=0,thresh=df.shape[1]-2)
Out[101]: 
   user_id   group_id    a     b     c    az
0        1          1   23   pro   5.5   234
1        2          1   32   che   3.3   342
```